# Does $a_n$ increasing imply $a_n-\frac{1}{n}$ strictly increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. 
>   If $(a_n)$ is increasing prove that $(a_n-1/n)$ is strictly increasing.

How can I start off this off this question via induction?

Comment: If $a_n=n+1/n$ then both $a_n$ and $a_n-\frac 1n$ are increasing.

Comment: How is an=n+1/n ?

Comment: Also can someone tell me how to format.

Comment: To disprove a proposed theorem, it suffices to exhibit a single counterexample.  I defined a particular sequence $a_n$ which, I believe, passes your requirements but which does not satisfy your conclusion hence the theorem, as stated, can not be correct.

Comment: As to formatting, there is a terrific tutorial here:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I understand, but for that you need to provide a counterexample if it decreasing? If it is at all.

Comment: Oh, you changed the question.  The original question said "prove $a_n-\frac 1n$ was decreasing".  My example is not a counterexample to the new question.

Comment: Yh sorry my mistake. So is there a counterexample to this proposed theorem?

Answer (score 1):

$(\frac{1}{n})$ is strictly decreasing, so $(-\frac{1}{n})$ is strictly increasing. Then $a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1} \geq a_{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} > a_{n}-\frac{1}{n}$.